# Unable to build java google cloud debugger on ubuntu server on virtualbox

Tags: java, ubuntu, virtualbox, google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to build the *java* google cloud debugger on `Ubuntu 15.10 Server` (guest) running on `Virtual Box 5.0.14` on `Mac OS X El Capitan` (host).

I'm following the build instructions from [cloud-debug-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java)

After installing `cmake`, `build-essential`, `oracle java 8`, `maven3` etc., I also had to make the following changes to `src/agent/Makefile` before running `./build.sh`:

1. Changed the `/path/to/java/` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/`
2. Added this `include`: `-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux`

So, my `INCLUDES` declaration looks like this:

`INCLUDES = \
        -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include \
        -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux \
        -I$(THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDE_PATH) \
        -I$(ANTLR_CPP_LIB_INCLUDE) \
        -I. \
        -I../codegen \
        -Iantlrgen \`

After that, the build runs fine but eventually fails when trying to build `expression_util.o`

**Error**:

`g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/home/ubuntu-java/Development/google-cloud-debugger/cloud-debug-java/third_party/install/include -I../../third_party/antlr/lib/cpp/v2_7_2/ -I. -I../codegen -Iantlrgen  -m64 -std=c++11 -fPIC -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-array-bounds -g0 -DSTANDALONE_BUILD -DGCP_HUB_CLIENT -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-strict-aliasing  -O3 -D NDEBUG -c expression_util.cc -o expression_util.o
In file included from expression_util.cc:25:0:
antlrgen/JavaExpressionLexer.hpp:4:54: fatal error: third_party/antlr/lib/cpp/antlr/config.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:190: recipe for target 'expression_util.o' failed
make: *** [expression_util.o] Error 1`

In the *generated* `JavaExpressionLexer.hpp` file, it's trying to `#include` `third_party/antlr/lib/cpp/antlr/config.hpp` and fails to find it.

In the project, I do see a `config.hpp`, but it's under `<project-root>/third_party/antlr/lib/cpp/v2_7_2/antlr/`.

I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [build.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/blob/master/build.sh) script? It should take care of ANTLR and other third party dependencies.

Specifically the build needs to set `THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable similarly to [build.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/blob/master/build.sh#L98).

Comment: Yes, I'm running `./build.sh` directly from under `<project-root>`. Would it help to post a log of the _entire_ run and my modified `build.sh`? About the `THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDE_PATH`, I'm pretty sure I have it in the script, but I'll double-check.